# How to know an activity is started from notification or other way (click from recent app lists, or open app directly)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I know there are some discussions about this question, but my case is different.

My case: LanchActivity(loading animation) -> MainActivity(including A and B two tabs) -> ThirdActivity. MainActivity release a notification. When click the notification, what I want is:

- If the app is in the background, bring the app to the foreground, and display tab B in MainActivity.
- If the app is killed, start the app, LanchActivity -> MainActivity, and then show tab B in MainActivity.

I have implemented above, I set MainActivity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Notification with the following setting:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LancherActivity.class);
resultIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
resultIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
         getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
serviceNotificationbuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
serviceNotification = serviceNotificationbuilder.build();
startForeground(1, serviceNotification);
```

In the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  mTabHost.setCurrentTab(B);
}
```

The reason I use singleTask lanchMode for MainActivity is to avoid create a new instance when everytime I click the notification. However, if I use above code, something happened I don't want to see.

- I start the ThirdActivity from Tab A, click back button back to MainActivity, the MainActivity shows Tab B
- Tab A displays in the foreground, click home button to show the home page, then resume the app from recent apps list, it will show Tab B as well, because `mTabHost.setCurrentTab(B);`

So the `mTabHost.setCurrentTab(B);` should only work when the MainActivity come from Notification. But I don't know MainActivity start from notification or other way(recent apps list or open app directly).

1. If the app is killed, Notification -> LancherActivity -> MainActivity. In this case I can set `resultIntent.putExtra("flag", "I from Notificaion");`, so I can use the flag to check whether the MainActivity is from Notification.
2. If the app is not killed , no matter it in the background or foreground, Notification -> MainActivity, it will go to MainActivity directly without through LancherActivity. So I don't know where the MainActivity come from.

Anyone has solutions, thanks?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for MainActivity and update your notification intent as below:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LancherActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("openTabB",true);// add this line
```

In your LaunchActivity, create a `boolean` field say `openTabB` and set it to `false`.
In onCreate  method of LaunchActivity, use this line

```
openTabB = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("openTabB");
```

Use the Intent of MainActivity caller inside LaunchActivity. Put `boolean` extra in that intent, key is `openTabB` and value is openTabB field.

Now, in your MainActivity, use below line:

```
openTabB = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("openTabB");
if(openTabB)
{
    //open tab B
} 
else
{
    // normal execution
}
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. First, I removed `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for MainActivity. If my app is still running in the background, when I click notification, it open MainActivity directly, don't through LancherActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You should save current tab's index in onPause() and restore it in onResume().

save index:

```
int index = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
```

restore index:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(index);
```

**Edit:**
The only difference between MainActivity start from notification or other way is start from notification need to go through onCreate() and other way doesn't.So you need to add a flag in onCreate().

```
private boolean flag;
private in mCurrentTab = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    flag = true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (flag)
        setCurrentTab(1); // set to B
    else
        setCurrentTab(mCurrentTab);
    flag = false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mCurrentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you understand what I need. I need go to Tab B when click the notification.

Comment: I test your solution, it doesn't work. If the app is still running in the background, When I click the notification, it goes to MainActivity but not goes through `onCreate()`.